# How to select the counter value in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver, cassandra-2.0

How exactly in CQL (or more importantly, in datastax java driver) I can query the value of the counter,  like 'WHERE counter > 5'?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql3/CQL.html#counters

So you can only query by key,  not by the counter value.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it with counters as Mikhail posted.  I also wanted to add a couple of extra points.  First, this is fundamentally unsupported for architectural reasons, and not because "CQL doesn't support it yet" or some other superficial reason.  And secondly, if you want to query by statistics (including counts), you need the following.

- A table that will allow querying by counter value. If you want range queries (<, > or equivalents) consider a schema where the count is the first clustering column (i.e.: `primary key(some_group, counter_value, {counted object id})`).  This will internally sort rows by counter value and thus give you fast lookups for queries like you specified.  You'll have to put some thought into what your partition key (`some_group`) will be.  There is a tradeoff between being able to partition the data across nodes and ease of querying globally.
- A way to update the sorted table that is scalable.  Two options here based on how fast data comes in:

  a) if updates are really infrequent, just update the sorted table in real time.  So when a counter is incremented, delete the old row and insert a new one.  This gives you immediate updates, but writes will be quite expesnive, so this won't scale if many rows are always changing.

  b) if writes are frequent OR if you can live with slightly stale data for your query-by-counter scenarios, consider running a periodic task that will read the latest counts and update the sorted table as appropriate.  If you have "big data" volumes going on, running this may have to be done in a Hadoop environment.